# PerformClick Method

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Could someone please explain in the simplest possible terms how the "PerformClick" method works? The Microsoft website says that it "Generates a Click event for the control" in question. However, it is unclear to me how to define what code gets executed on a click. The relevant websites are found include code written in C# as opposed to VB which i am using. Any help regarding how to properly use this method with buttons would be much appreciated. Thank you.

The aforementioned websites:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.button.performclick?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_Button_PerformClick

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.ibuttoncontrol.performclick?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_IButtonControl_PerformClick

Comment: The samples show you the click event and code that runs when clicked!  To change the language, up at the top find the menu listing `C#` open it and select VB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets say you make a button in vb, and when you click it, you want some code to execute.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Your code
End Sub
```

Clicking the button is not the only way the programme can get to this sub.

```
Button1.PerformClick()
```

The above line of code calls the subroutine Button1_Click as an alternative to writing:

```
Button1_Click(sender, e)
```

Comment: Oh, thank you. The method doesn't actually do what I assumed it did. if I have already defined a set of buttons using a hashtable where each entry is defined as a new button with given properties, how would I go about adding functionality to all of those buttons?

Comment: @Gondola : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/addhandler-statement

Comment: @Gondola Since David Popovici 's answer did answer your question, please accept his answer by clicking the check mark (tick mark) to the left of the question.

Comment: @Gondola To add functionality to all your buttons, you would have to make a new sub for each of them that handles their click. This can be done manually or by automatically by double clicking the buttons in design view